# If $p(x)=q(x)$ for all $x\in S$, are the coefficients equal?

Tags: polynomials

> **Claim:** If $p(x)=q(x)$ for every possible $x \in S$, then every coeffient of $x^i$ in $p(x)$ equals every coefficient of $x^i$ in
>   $q(x)$ for all natural $i$.

($p(x),q(x)$ written in standard form, with real coefficients)

For which all cases is this true?

1. $S=\mathbb{R}$
2. $S=\mathbb{Z}$
3. $S=\mathbb{Z}^{+}$
4. $S= \text{some infinite set that tends to infinity}$
5. $S=\text{some infinite set between finite constants}$

This is not a homework question, I came up with it myself. I have no idea how such questions are formally proved, so I may not even understand your proofs. However, I am interested in knowing which of these cases are true.

Comment: I guess that $p$ and $q$ are real polynomials?

Comment: What is a "set tending to infinity" (what does it mean for a set to tend to infinity)?

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer: I suppose he means a set $\{a_i\}_{i\in I}\subseteq \Bbb R$ such that for any $M>0$ there exists an $i'\in I$ with the property that $|a_{i'}|>M$.

Comment: A polynomial of degree _n_ is fully specified when there are _n_ different points given. So for an infinite S **yes**. That _n_ points are needed to either have all coefficients (un-)solvable is a bit of elementary math.

Comment: @Clayton Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @JoopEggen: A polynomial of degree n is fully specified when there are n+1 different points given.

Comment: @MaartenHilferink I am blushing, thanks ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is known that any non-zero polynomial with real coefficients has only a finite number of roots. The constant zero polynomial has any number as its root, and is the only polynomial with infinite number of roots.

Now, if $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite set, and $\forall x \in S :p(x)=q(x)$, then $p-q$ is a polynomial that has an infinite number of roots and must be equal to zero polynomial. This means that $p$ and $q$ have equal coefficients.

Comment: This is correct given that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are polynomials; otherwise, there might be varying oscillation between discrete points (such as in $\Bbb Z$; $\sin(2\pi x)$ and $\sin(4\pi x)$ are equal on $\Bbb Z$ without being equal on $\Bbb R$).

Comment: @Clayton the question is tagged with `polynomials` tag.

Comment: Does that imply all 5 cases are true?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code since the sets in all your 5 cases are infinite, it is true for all of them.

Comment: @lisyarus Okay. Thanks a lot!